# Using Docs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

[image: Screenshot of MongoDB shell commands]

[Just to clarify, "zips" is NOT a db as can be seen in this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG22I.png)

I have a database: Homework, and collection: zips [ which contains US zips codes data] It seems I can access the data only using 'use homework'

Can somebody please explain why we cannot access the document data from Collections? Hope the image will explain it more clearly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
use zips
```

is switching to the database `zips` and not as you (probably) are expecting making the collection `zips` the default collection.

In 99% of cases you will only access one database and never use the command `use` more than once if you forgot to set the database name in your login credentials&url

So, when you login you should be in the database `homework`, and if not you can say

```
 use homework
```

to switch to the homework database -- Once in the homework database, the command

```
 show collections
```

should give you a list of all the collections in your database, so in your case `zips` and any other collections you may have created in that database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just want one little clarification. In this case, zips is supposed to lie within "homework", shouldn't we be drilling down to collection levels to search for the data.

Comment: Added more info -- hope that helps